# Unreal 4.25 - Player Camera Manager - how can I get the pitch?

Tags: camera, blueprint, pitch

*In the context of the player controller possessing many different characters (or pawns)*

**I try make my own camera manager**

with the below blueprint, I almost get the regular behavior of the camera following the movements of the main character

but going up down with the mouse, the **pitch is not applied**

if the yaw (**Add Controller Yaw Input**) is changing the actor's rotation (that I use below)

**where can I get the pitch of the player character ? (applied with Add Controller PitchInput)**

thanks for helping me on this

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

one gotta use

Get Player Controller -> Get Control Rotation